# Signing VMware drivers on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, ubuntu-18.04, vmware-player

I am trying to setup VMware Workstation 14 Player on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and as expected, facing a challenge with unsigned 'vmmon' and 'vmnet' drivers. As a consequence,  'Virtual machine monitor' and 'Virtual ethernet' services fails to start.

As per the instructions on numerous posts here, I am executing the below commands:

- Generate a key pair:

  $ `openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=VMware/"`
- sign the modules:

  $ sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vmmon)

  $ sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n vmnet)
- import the key to your MOK (Module owned Key) and select a password (you will to need this password on reboot, so it will be enrolled.

  $ mokutil --import MOK.der

All the posts say that assigning the key should be sufficient. But in my case, this step fails and the key fails to assign

```
# modinfo vmmon
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/misc/vmmon.ko
supported:      external
license:        GPL v2
description:    VMware Virtual Machine Monitor.
author:         VMware, Inc.
srcversion:     4E7C451E151FBF78CD20320
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
name:           vmmon
vermagic:       4.15.0-33-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
```

Note that the key fails to assign. Please help me resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance for the help.